# How to get particular values from JSON response Android?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get particular `values (ID as a string, branches of address_one and two)` from below mentioned `JSON` response. Please help me.

My Response

```
{ 
   "response":{ 
      "school":"inox",
      "grad":"first",
     },
   "ID":"1234567890101112",
   "branches":{ 
      "address_one":"ISA",
      "address_two":"DOA"
   },
   "my school":{ 
      "inox":"first"
   },
}
```

My Code :

```
try {
        JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("response");
        String school_value = data.getString(KEY_SCHOOL);
        String grad_value = data.getString(KEY_GRAD);

       System.out.println("RESPONSE:" + data + school_value + grad_value);

     } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by This way you can access all the Values....`    try {
        JSONObject responceData = response.getJSONObject("response");
        String school_value = responceData.getString(KEY_SCHOOL);
        String grad_value = responceData.getString(KEY_GRAD);

```
    String id = response.getString("1234567890101112")

    JSONObject brances = response.getJSONObject("branches");
    String address_one = brances.getString("address_one");
    String address_two = brances.getString("address_one");

    JSONObject myScool = response.getJSONObject("my school");
    String inox = brances.getString("inox");

    System.out.println("Responce in Json: " + responce.toString);
    System.out.println("Responce extracted: " + school_value + " " + grad_value + 
            " " + id + " " +address_one + " " + address_two + " " + inox);


} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

`ID` is in `response` JSONObject. `address_one` and `address_two` keys inside `branches` JSONObject which is inside `response` JSONObject :

```
// get ID
String strID= response.optString("ID");

// get branches JSONObject 
JSONObject jsonBranches = response.getJSONObject("branches");

// get address_one and address_two from jsonBranches

//address_one
String address_one= jsonBranches.optString("address_one");

//address_two
String address_two= jsonBranches.optString("address_two");
```

Answer (score 0):

if your response in string then first convert it in json object and after that parse if not get then after check your parameter match with json key

```
 JSONObject response =new JSONObject(response_string);
  JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("response");
  String school_value = data.getString("school");
  String grad_value = data.getString("grad");
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the snippet you've posted is not a valid json. The correct form is, I think, without commas before closing curly brackets:

```
{
  "response": {
    "school": "inox",
    "grad": "first"
  },
  "ID": "1234567890101112",
  "branches": {
    "address_one": "ISA",
    "address_two": "DOA"
  },
  "my school": {
    "inox": "first"
  }
}
```

Beside of that your code seems to be fine. To get addresses first get branches object and then get address strings:

```
JSONObject branches = response.getJSONObject("branches");
String address1 = branches.getString("address_one");
String address2 = branches.getString("address_two");
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```
 try {
    JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("response");
  JSONObject branch= data.getJSONObject("branches");
    String schoolValue = data.getString("KEY_SCHOOL");
    String gradValue = data.getString("KEY_GRAD");
String id = data.getString("ID");
String addressOne= branch.getString("address_one");
String addressTwo= branch.getString("address_two");


   System.out.println("RESPONSE:" + data + school_value + grad_value);

 } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this with your code and you will get id printed in SOP

```
 try {
            JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("response");
            String school_value = data.getString(KEY_SCHOOL);
            String grad_value = data.getString(KEY_GRAD);
             String id=response.getString("ID");

    System.out.println("RESPONSE:" + data + school_value + grad_value+id);

     } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```